# default constructor of stl vector

Tags: c++, stl

the signature of default constructor is

```
explicit vector (const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

How to read this?
Why is it not prefixed by  a

```
template <class ....>
```

what does the first and only argument

```
const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()
```

mean?

are all stl container classes already prefixed by a `template <class ...>`

How does it define the type used for every element of a vector if its not followed by a template instruction?

Can anybody show an example using the default method?

Comment: Because it is the constructor *declaration*, which is declared inside of the class.

Comment: Because `vector` is a class *template*, i.e. it's a template from which `vector<...>` classes (like `vector<int, std::allocator<int> >`) can be created (instantiated). There should be a `template < class, class > ` preceding the `class vector`.

Comment: I cant figure out what is the significance of the first argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it not prefixed by a `template <class...>`?

Because it's inside the definition of the `vector` class template. Inside the class template, you don't specify that each member is also a template. Adding a `template` specification to a member would give it extra template parameters, in addition to the class parameters, which aren't needed for this constructor.

> what does the first and only argument mean?

That's an optional argument, which can be used to supply a custom memory allocator to give you more control over how the vector uses memory. Normally, you'd miss that argument out and get the default value. The default is an instance of `vector<T>::allocator_type`, which is an alias for `std::allocator<T>`. This will allocate memory from the free store, using the global `new` and `delete` operators.